# play-framework: testing with fake Application

Tags: playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I'm trying to test a functionality like this:

```
@Test
    public void testAddTask() {
        FakeApplication fakeApplication = fakeApplication(inMemoryDatabase());
        start(fakeApplication);
        Task task=new Task();
        task.title="test Task";
        task.save();
        assertThat(Task.find.where().ilike("title", "task")).isNull();
        stop(fakeApplication);

    }
```

which succeed which Is wrong 
while

```
@Test
    public void testAddTask(){
        running(fakeApplication(inMemoryDatabase()), new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Task task=new Task();
                task.title="test Task";
                task.save();
                assertThat(Task.find.where().ilike("title", "task")).isNull();
            }
        });
    }
```

fails and that's what I expect.

shouldn't `startfakeapplication`behave the same as  `running(fakeApplication()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it [does the same](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/2.1.0/framework/src/play-test/src/main/java/play/test/Helpers.java#L364)

```java
/**
 * Executes a block of code in a running application.
 */
public static synchronized void running(FakeApplication fakeApplication, final Runnable block) {
    try {
        start(fakeApplication);
        block.run();
    } finally {
        stop(fakeApplication);
    }
}
```

Cause of difference may be not cleaning after running some other test. `running()` has `try..finally` construct, putting `stop(fakeApplication);` into method annotated with `@After` is recommended (and initialization of `fakeApplication` in `@Before`).

I dislike `running()` helper method because it doesn't allow to throw exceptions inside `run()`.